# Siddhi query: Unable frame query using external time batch windows

Tags: siddhi

We are evaluating Siddhi for its CEP capabilities and wanted to write a paper describing its querying power to solve our rules use cases.

While writing the paper, I wanted to give a simple rule. On the data set

```
ts                          Stock       Bid                       
------------------------------------------------------------------
2011-07-12 10:23:54.0       abc         10.12                     
2011-07-12 10:23:58.0       abc         10.34                     
2011-07-12 10:23:59.0       abc         10.75                     
2011-07-12 10:25:15.0       abc         11.98                     
2011-07-12 10:25:16.0       abc         <null>                    
2011-07-12 10:25:22.0       xyz         45.16                     
2011-07-12 10:25:27.0       xyz         49.33                     
2011-07-12 10:31:12.0       xyz         65.25                     
2011-07-12 10:31:15.0       xyz         <null>
```

The requirement: Alert if the number of same stock is greater than or equal to some percentage, say 60% within a window of 40 seconds.

So far I am able to arrive at this query.

```
define stream StockStream (ts long,stock string, bid double); 
define window StockEventWindow (ts long, stock string, bid double)    externalTimeBatch(ts,40 sec, ts, 3 sec); 
@info(name = 'query1') 
from StockStream 
insert into StockEventWindow; 
@info(name = 'query2') 
from StockEventWindow 
select ts, stock, bid, count(stock) as c 
group by stock 
insert into OutputStream;
```

The result obtained at OutputStream:

```
[Event{timestamp=1310446439000, data=[1310446439000, abc, 10.75, 3], isExpired=false}]

[Event{timestamp=1310446516000, data=[1310446516000, abc, 0.0, 2], isExpired=false}, Event{timestamp=1310446527000, data=[1310446527000, xyz, 49.33, 2], isExpired=false}]

[Event{timestamp=1310446872000, data=[1310446872000, xyz, 65.25, 1], isExpired=false}]

[Event{timestamp=1310446875000, data=[1310446875000, xyz, 0.0, 1], isExpired=false}]
```

Unable to move ahead from here to get desired result. I was searching for a function/operator which provides me the size of window, thereby I could compare the stock count with window size (as count(stock)/windowSize >= 0.5) and did not find any.

The expected results are

stock size is 3 and window size is 3 so 100%

```
[Event{timestamp=1310446439000, data=[1310446439000, abc, 10.75, 3], isExpired=false}]
```

stock size is 1 and window size is 1 so 100%

```
[Event{timestamp=1310446872000, data=[1310446872000, xyz, 65.25, 1], isExpired=false}]
```

stock size is 1 and window size is 1 so 100%

```
[Event{timestamp=1310446875000, data=[1310446875000, xyz, 0.0, 1], isExpired=false}]
```

All these results have the count of stock greater than 60% of window size.

Also I wanted to know If I can maintain any state within window?

Comment: I need a small clarification on your requirement. Do you want to collect all data rows arrived within 40 secs and identify if there are entries belonging to same stock which occupy 60% of the collection or do you want to see whether any stock has increased its value by 60% within 40 seconds. I imagine its former depending on your work. But needed clarifications.

Comment: @Tishan yes its former and not percentage increase

Answer (score 0):

First [define the window](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.0/docs/query-guide/#named-window)

```
define window StockEventWindow (ts long, stock string, bid double)    externalTimeBatch(ts,40 sec, ts);
```

Then a query to insert into window

```
from StockStream 
insert into StockEventWindow;
```

Then [join query](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.0/docs/query-guide/#join-window) to check current window size

```
from StockStream join StockEventWindow
select stock, count(*) as windowSize
insert into windowSizeStream;
```

Then query to check num of relevant stock events in window

```
from StockStream join StockEventWindow on StockStream.stock == StockEventWindow.stock
select stock, count(*) as stockSize
insert into stockSizeStream;
```

Then [pattern query](https://siddhi.io/en/v5.0/docs/query-guide/#pattern) to calculate percentage and get the decision

```
From every e1=windowSizeStream -> e2=stockSizeStream[e1.stock == stock]
select e1.stock, (e2.stockSize/e1.windowSize)*100 as percentage
having percentage>60
insert into alert stream;
```

I did not run the queries. But above line of implementation will work with sync architecture that siddhi has.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Now I am gettting this error. 
`Exception in thread "main" io.siddhi.query.api.exception.SiddhiAppValidationException: Error on 'bdf65b0a-da05-4291-9140-99e440bc7a7a' @ Line: 10. Position: 12, near 'stock'. Input Stream: StockStream with reference: null and Input Stream: StockEventWindow with reference: null contains attribute with same name 'stock'`. 

The line is `select stock, count(*) as windowSize`

Comment: also please provide me with link to know more on what is this "sync architecture"

Comment: I amended the queries in answer. Below is the link to event execution flow architecture. As you can observe it is an execution chain. sync architecture means that one thread will carry an event/event collection throughout the full execution path without handing over